# Create website header using CakePHP block

Tags: cakephp

I am building website using CakePHP 4.1.5. I need the same header for all pages. There will be link `login` (no user is logged) or `logout` (if user is logged in). I need use a block probably, but I do not know, how to create it. In [cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views.html#view-blocks) is an example, but I do not know, where exactly should I enter the code. Note: how to create an Element is clear.

Comment: Anything that goes on all pages should go in your default Layout template.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I was thinking about inserting a block into layout, but maybe that is not necessary. Thank you

Comment: Blocks can be useful for things like this. They can help to keep things organized, and make the system more flexible overall. But they can also be overkill. Whether to bother with one is a situational decision with no right or wrong answer.